# How to force MVC application to ask for credentials with Windows authentication enabled

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, windows-authentication

I am working on an application that retrieves some data from the API of another application and displays it in the table. I have set up Windows authentication (based on membership in a certain AD group) and it works, but I would like to make it so it ALWAYS asks the user for credentials when trying to access the desired page. How can I do this?

I am a beginner in ASP.NET so I didn't exactly come up with anything to try, I've done some googling but did not find anything related. And when I thought I did, it was something really old and not applicable anymore.

Here is my appsettings.json:

```
"SecuritySettings": {
    "ADGroup": "ad\\GSRLB2P_ISP_ITSD_INFRA_VST" }
```

Controller:

```cs
    public class DeviceController : Controller
    {
        [Authorize(Policy = "ADRoleOnly")]
        public IActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString)
...
```

Startup:

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
            });

            //services.AddAuthentication(IISDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy("ADRoleOnly", policy => policy.RequireRole(Configuration["SecuritySettings:ADGroup"]));
            });

            services.AddMvc(config =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();

                config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });
        }
```

I know that the authentication works because when I change the group name to something else, it is not letting me access the page. But I would like the page to ask for credentials anyway.
Is it possible?

Comment: Do you mean you only want to ask for extra credentials on accessing one specific page and leave everything else to the Windows authentication? Otherwise why not turn it off?

Comment: No no, I want the page to ask user for his windows credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You could send an HTTP 401 response the first time a user hits that page by using `return HttpUnauthorized()`.

Windows Authentication works like this:

1. The browser requests the page.
2. The server sends back a 401 response indicating that it accepts "Negotiate" authentication.
3. If the site is trusted, the browser resends the request with the users credentials.

If the server then sends *another* 401, then the browser will prompt for new credentials.

If you do this, you should [enable sessions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.2) and store a flag in the session to say you already sent the 401 so you can let them in the next time. Something like this:

```
[Authorize(Policy = "ADRoleOnly")]
public IActionResult Index(string sortOrder, string searchString) {
    if (!HttpContext.Session.Keys.Contains("Sent401")) {
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("Sent401", "yes");
        return HttpUnauthorized();
    }

    ...

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try something like this for your controller method:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    ...
    return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();   // force a login prompt
}
```

This will cause the browser to throw up a login prompt on page load.  As another answer here said, you'll also need to set some kind of condition before returning that result, such as checking if the current user is authenticated; otherwise, the code above will just prompt the user repeatedly.

Answer (score -2):

```
<system.web>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
    <authentication mode="Windows"></authentication>
</system.web>
```

Comment: This should go to web.config right? As far as I know there is no web.config file in ASP.NET Core 2.2 anymore...

Comment: All this does is enable impersonation. There is no reason to do that.

Comment: But yes, web.config is still a thing with ASP.NET Core, but only if you're hosting in IIS. It tells IIS what to do.